How to properly compare a single diagnostic test in two subpopulations
Suppose I have a diagnostic test with a binary response. I have performed this test on some population.
Now, I split this population in two subgroups (e.g. male/female), and would like to check if some parameter of my test, such as sensitivity and specificity, is biased towards some group, or if the difference between these parameters for each group is statistically significant. What would be the proper way to do this?
Other scenarios I'm interested into is if I have more than two subgroups (e.g. age groups), and if the size of each group is very unbalanced.
Thank you!

If the outcome of the test is binary then you can run a logistic regression on your data.
